# Promise is opening too many HTTP Connections (Example)

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple code that calls an external API

```js
const promises = [];
for (const elem of data) {
  const carId = Number(elem.carId);
  promises.push(getCarData(carId));
}
console.log('Waiting for all promises to finish');
const result = await Promise.allSettled(promises);

export const getCarData = async (carId: number) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const car = await API.getCar(carId);
        if (!car) {
            return reject(new Error('Could not find car'));
        }
        return resolve(car);
    });
}


-- API --

import axios from 'axios';
import https from 'https';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  })
});

static getCar = async(carId: number) => {
  try {
    const response = await axiosInstance.get(`${baseUrl}/v1/car/${carId}.json`);
    const car = response.data;
    return car;
  } catch (err) {
    // something else
  }
}
```

**There are like 10.000 requests being made in the promise array for each element in `data`**. It starts working well but after some time I start getting errors in some of the promises

> "connect EMFILE IP:443 - Local (undefined:undefined)"

***I checked and it seems that it's related to the OS not wanting to open more sockets. This is hosted in AWS obviously, so what can I do to slow down the requests and not open so many connections at the same time?***

Answer (score 0):

**Promise.allSettled** is part of the [concurrent methos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#promise_concurrency).
You could write your own *promise handle* or find [some package](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords%3Athrottle%2Cconcurrently).

simple example assuming each request takes the same time:

```js
//run multiple promises sequentialy.
async function runSeq(ps:Promise[]){
  for(const p of ps){
    await p;
  }
}

//fake 20 requests.
const ps =new Array(20).fill(Promise.resolve(0)).map((_v,i)=>i);

//split into an array with 3 elements.
d3=a.length/3;
const pss = [a.splice(0,Math.ceil(d3)),a.splice(0,Math.ceil(d3)),a]

//execute 3 concurrent promises.
await Promise.all(pss.map(ps=>await runSeq(ps)))
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem. There are 10000 concurrent requests and the OS disallows any more requests to be opened. It has little to do with running them sequentially.

Comment: the problem is most certainly not the amount of requests, the problem is the amount of concurrent requests.